# How to rotate polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.0

how do i rotate a polygon drawn from the Create Features menu?

Answer (score 6):

Use the rotate tool on the Editor menu:
[image]

Comment: FYI the small x that appears when you select something is the anchor. That can be dragged to another location for better anchor.

Comment: Is there any other GIS software with the similar "interactive" rotate Polygons option ? I Know maifold has a rotate by angle command in the transform toolbar.